# How to block a python thread as long as there is no data from stdin?

Tags: python, multithreading, optimization, stdin, blocking

My function is supposed to check if there is stdin input, and if there is, put it into a queue:

```
def readUserInputThread(keyboard_queue):
    kb = KBHit()

    while True:
        time.sleep(0.01)
        if kb.kbhit():
            c = kb.getch()
            keyboard_queue.put(c)
```

The function is supposed to run as fast as possible, as the pressed keys are printed out instantly. It should also catch special keys, like enter, escape .... etc.

It uses the KBHit implementation, that I found [here](https://gist.github.com/michelbl/efda48b19d3e587685e3441a74457024).

My issue: The code is active waiting. This function runs as a thread and it's CPU usage is to high (around 4%). I think there might be a better solution, using some sort of flag or event, that unblocks the thread for a short period of time.

Comment: Isn’t this just `select`?